# Node.JS / Express.JS CouchDB Session Storage

Tags: session, node.js, couchdb, express

Is there any working Session Storage or do I have to use `MemoryStore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any session store that uses CouchDB. You can use MemoryStore but when your process restarts you lose all your sessions. I think most people use redis to store their sessions but having yet an other extra technology in your stack can be undesirable.